# eclipse update-site: Plugin version not shown in software install dialog

Tags: eclipse, update-site

I have created an eclipse plugin along with an eclipse feature and I have created an *update site* using eclipses export mechanism.

My problem is, that when I try to install the feature from this update site I always see the version number `0.0.0`, although the configured version is `1-SNAPSHOT`.
[image: install dialog]

I searched the `xml` files generated into the site but at any place in there the correct version number is written, eg.:
[image: content.xml]

I suspect that I have to add something in the `content.xml` but I couldn't fine any clue, what to change.

What do I need to change in the sites `xml` files to get the plugin version shown in eclipses software installation Dialog?

Comment: `1-SNAPSHOT` is not a valid [semantic version](https://semver.org/). In your `feature.xml` set the version to something like `1.0.0.qualifier` (`qualifier` will be replaced by a time stamp). Generally, better use Tycho for building.

Comment: The first three parts of the version **must** be numbers.

Comment: I really expected eclipse to treat the version as a simple string for display purpose, but it looks like it is doing some magic behind the scenes...

Comment: @howlger according to `semver.org` the version `1.0.0.qualifier` is also not valid even with `qualifier` replaced since the label must be separated by a dash... ;o)

Comment: Eclipse implements [OSGi](https://www.osgi.org/) where `1-SNAPSHOT` is an invalid version.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @howlger and @greg-449!

The version has to match the `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH` pattern an the Label, if any, has to be separated by a dot, not by a dash.

Any other pattern is shown as version `0.0.0` in the software install dialog of eclipse.